# three.js - Set the rotation of an object in relation to its own axes

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a static 3D prism out of point clouds with specific numbers of particles in each. I've got the  the corner coordinates of each side of the prism based on the angle of turn, and tried spawning the particles in the area bound by these coordinates. Instead, the resulting point clouds have kept only the bottom left coordinate.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ7Q8.png

I've tried to set the rotation of each cloud object such that their edges meet, but they will rotate only around the world centre. I gather this is something to do with rotation matrices and Euler angles, but, having been trying to work them out for 3 solid days, I've despaired. (I'm a sociologist, not a dev, and haven't touched graphics before this project.)

Please help? How do I set the rotation on each face of the prism? Or maybe there is a more sensible way to get the particles to spawn in the correct area in the first place?

The code:

```
// draw the particles

var n = 0;

do {

    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();    
    var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({size: 1, vertexColors: true, color: 0xffffff});    

    for (i = 0; i < group[n]; i++) {

        if (geom.vertices.length < group[n]){

            var particle = new THREE.Vector3(

                Math.random() * screens[n].bottomrightback.x + screens[n].bottomleftfront.x,                    
                Math.random() * screens[n].toprightback.y + screens[n].bottomleftfront.y,                   
                Math.random() * screens[n].bottomrightfront.z + screens[n].bottomleftfront.z);

           geom.vertices.push(particle);       
           geom.colors.push(new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0x00ffff));             
        }
    }

    var system = new THREE.PointCloud(geom, material);
    scene.add(system);

    **// something something matrix Euler something?**


n++
}           
while (n < numGroups);
```

Comment: Consider creating a geometry in the shape of a prism and then generate random points inside the faces of the geometry: `THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( geometry, numPoints )`. You can find `GeometryUtils.js` in the `examples/js/utils` directory. Try it with a `CylinderGeometry` first.

Comment: Aha, I'd hoped something along these lines existed, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried to set the rotation of each cloud object such that their
>   edges meet, but they will rotate only around the world centre.

It is true they only rotate around 0,0,0. The simple solution then is to move the object to the center, rotate it, and then move it back to its original position.

For example (Code not tested so might take a bit of tweaking):

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();

var movetocenter = new THREE.Matrix4();
movetocenter.makeTranslation(-x, -y, -z);

var rotate = new THREE.Matrix4();
rotate.makeRotationFromEuler(); //Build your rotation here

var moveback = new THREE.Matrix4();
moveback .makeTranslation(x, y, z);

m.multiply(movetocenter);
m.multiply(rotate);
m.multiply(moveback); 

//Now you can use geometry.applyMatrix(m)
```

Comment: Suddenly matrices make a great deal more sense. It was the multiplication step I was missing out. Thanks!